# How to read exception passed as the second parameter to Environment.FailFast()?

Tags: c#, exception

[MSDN Documentation for FailFast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.failfast?view=netframework-4.8) (second overload) mention:

> Immediately terminates a process after writing a message to the
>   Windows Application event log, and then includes the message **and
>   exception** information in error reporting to Microsoft.

My context is a Windows Service application having a generic try/catch block that use NLog to log the error, then call Environment.FailFast(message, ex) to forcefully end the process.

My NLog target print the exception successfully, but the Windows Event Viewer does not. I have the message, and the callstack leading to FailFast (bunch of Task/MoveNext useless generic stack), but NOT the call stack of the exception passed as the second parameter.

```
private static void FailFast(string message, Exception exception)
{
    try
    {
        Log.Fatal(message, exception);
        NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
            Environment.FailFast(message, exception);
    }
}
```

So I have a test function that throw an NotSupportedException with a string test, and pass "Failed to start" as the message in my try/catch block calling my FailFast method.

What get logged in NLog:

```
Failed to start.
System.NotSupportedException: test
   at Application.Host.test()
   at Application.Host.<Start>d__5.MoveNext()
```

What get logged in Windows Event Viewer (notice no mention of the "test" string or the test() function):

```
Application: Application.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
Message: Failed to start.
Stack:
   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String, System.Exception)
   at Application.FailFast(System.String, System.Exception)
   at Application.Host+<Start>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.__Canon ByRef)
   at Application.Host.Start()
   at Application.Program+<Main>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.__Canon ByRef)
   at Application.Program.Main(System.String[])
   at Application.Program.<Main>(System.String[])
```

Comment: Read the documentation again. It never said it would write the exception information to the event log. It said it would send it to Microsoft's error reporting. It only promised to write the *message* to the event log, and it seems to have done so.

Comment: So this "Microsoft's error reporting" is telemetry data sent to their server? No way to read it to help debugging my own application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Damien_The_Unbeliever mentioned, Microsoft's error reporting (WER) is not the same as the Event Viewer. You can see the list of reports sent to Microsoft by typing "View all problem reports" in the start menu or by going under:

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Security and Maintenance\Problem Reports

From there you can read the exception type that triggered the error (in my case NotSupportedException), but not the call stack.